# Does httputil reverse proxy handle streaming response from a server?

Tags: http, go, server, reverse-proxy

httputil reverse proxy (https://golang.org/pkg/net/http/httputil/#ReverseProxy ) takes request from a client, transfers it to corresponding server and returns the response back. Does it handle streaming response as well from a server?

By streaming response I mean if server is sending data in chunks (like large image upload or image download). If yes, then how does it handle it?

Comment: It handles it like any other response. Why do you think it would it be any different? (the go documentation generally does what it says it's going to do, and any discrepancies can be filed as bugs)

Comment: I don't see anything in go description. Maybe it is handled, not sure though.Could you point me to that link if you know?

Comment: It says it proxies the response back to the client, and doesn’t mention exceptions. Servers always send data in chunks (packets), and usually use chunked encoding, but there is no such thing as a special type of “streaming response”

Comment: I think in case of streaming you must disable context deadline